# Word for "Town meeting"?

Tags: word-requests

I'm looking for a word for the phrase "Town meeting". The best I can find is タウンミーティング, but is there a better word I could use? Would 町の会合 work or is that too literal? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong with タウンミーティング, I'd say. There are terms like 寄り合い (also spelled 寄合) if you want to find a somewhat similar government practice in Japan. However, I wouldn't say that can be a translation per se, because connotations for the implied period in history, the larger society's socio-economic reality are vastly different.

町の会合 sounds rather like a description than a name of something.